# Unable to identify the proper regular expression in Jemter

Tags: jmeter

I'm facing issue while identifying one regular expression. I have the response body like below

```
|0|hiddenField|__EVENTTARGET||0|hiddenField|__EVENTARGUMENT||0|hiddenField|__LASTFOCUS||36|hiddenField|__VIEWSTATE_ID|**247f333f-b943-46ce-9ab6-6ed3f336bf84**|0|hiddenField|__VIEWSTATE||0|hiddenField|__VIEWSTATEENCRYPTED||47|asyncPostBackControlIDs||ctl00$cplMain$btnProductSearch,btnProductSearch|93|postBackControlIDs||ctl00$cplMain$btnViewShoppingCart,,ctl00$cplMain$btnOrderCart1,,ctl00$cplMain$ExportToExcel0,|250|updatePanelIDs||tctl00$cplMain$updMessage,,tctl00$cplMain$updTotalValueExGST,,tctl00$cplMain$updNumberOfLines,,tctl00$cplMain$updNumberOfProducts,,tctl00$cplMain$updPriceUpdate,,tctl00$cplMain$udpSearchMessage,udpSearchMessage,tctl00$cplMain$updProductSearchResults,|0|childUpdatePanelIDs|||243|panelsToRefreshIDs||ctl00$cplMain$updMessage,,ctl00$cplMain$updTotalValueExGST,,ctl00$cplMain$updNumberOfLines,,ctl00$cplMain$updNumberOfProducts,,ctl00$cplMain$updPriceUpdate,,ctl00$cplMain$udpSearchMessage,udpSearchMessage,ctl00$cplMain$updProductSearchResults,|3|asyncPostBackTimeout||600|22|formAction||./ProductOrdering.aspx|23|pageTitle||Product Search/Ordering|38|scriptStartupBlock|ScriptContentNoTags|window.scrolltoloc='udpSearchMessage';|
```

For the highlighted (247f333f-b943-46ce-9ab6-6ed3f336bf84) one I want to write the regular expression. I tried like `VIEWSTATE_ID|(.*?)|0|hiddenField|__VIEWSTATE|`. It seems to be wrong. Can anyone suggest me which one should I specify for these kind of regular expressions.

Regular expression test result

[image]

Answer (score 0):

In [JMeter regular expressions](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/regular_expressions.html) `|` is a [meta-character](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/regular_expressions.html#meta_chars) which needs escaping by `\` so you need to amend your regular expression to look like:

```
VIEWSTATE_ID\|(.*?)\|0\|hiddenField\|__VIEWSTATE\|
```

Demo:

[image]

If you have problems with coming up with a proper regular expression you can always use [Boundary Extractor](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/the-boundary-extractor-vs-the-regular-expression-extractor-in-jmeter), all you need to do is to provide left and right boundaries ant it will extract everything in-between

[image]

Moreover it works faster and consumes less resources

Comment: Thank you, it helped me and I was able go successful.

Comment: Another small help required. I have some parameters in my code as __EVENTTARGET= ctl00$cplMain$btnViewShoppingCart. Do we need to handle these parameters as well. And one more thing is, I want to send a unique reference number every time. How to do these 2 things